# How to use generated sequence number before persisting?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My scenario is very simple. I have an `entityID` identity field in the `@Entity` class and the DB (Oracle, which I'm not sure that matters):

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="ENTITY_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SEQ_GENERIC", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ENTITY_SEQ_GEN")
@Column(name="ENTITY_ID")
private long entityID;
```

I have another field called, let's say, `entityReadableID` and that should be a String consisting of the stringified entityID concatenated with another String field from the entity.  E.g. if entityID is *1234*, entityReadableID may be something like *1234ABC*.

My problem is that, as far as I know, the value of entityID is not known before the row is created in the DB but I need to concatenate the entityReadableID using its value.  Is there a way to fetch the value of the sequence generated ID before the row is created in the DB so that I can use it to generate the other ID?  I know I can make it an insert with that field being null and then make an update once I know what entityID is but that solution seems less than elegant.

The way I am hoping Hibernate/Oracle may be able to support this is if Hibernate can somehow "reserve/issue" the next generated value for the entity being processed before the actual persistence, let me know what it is so I can manipulate with it, then at the end persist it.

Comment: Why do you have this field in the first place? It's redundant, since it's the result of the concatenation of two other fields.

Comment: because it needs to be generated by default, shown in the UI, then the user can change it if (s)he chooses

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to persist (and flush) the entity without this field, and then compute it.

Comment: that is the less elegant solution i was hoping to avoid.  thanks

Comment: So you prefer the error-prone solution by fetching the last id, generate your field and pray to your god, that no other entity already took your id?

Comment: of course, there would have to be locking mechanisms within the DB to prevent that very obvious scenario...  such as the sequence issuing IDs and, once an ID has been issued, increment the next value for whoever asks for the next one.  that could happen if the issuance of IDs is done independently of its use

Comment: in fact, i had implemented several solutions just like that with an ID table and a class that was accessing it but that was all manually coded JDBC, not Hibernate.  the ID generator class would increment the persisted ID value once an ID was requested of it regardless of whether the value was used (in fact, it didn't know if it was used or not as it didn't have to).  i was hoping Hibernate would have something out of the box

Comment: I suggest you change your requirement. It embodies both a contradiction in terms and a violation of 3rd normal form.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the generated Id before persisting of that entity by not using sequence directly for that entity, I mean use a separated entity for that sequence, so your entity should be something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY"
)
public class EntityClass implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long entityId;
    private String entityRelatedId;

    public EntityClass() {
    }
    // you may have other constructors

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long getEntityId() {
        return this.entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(Long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ENTITY_RELATED_ID", length = 50)
    public String getEntityRelatedId() {
        return this.entityRelatedId;
    }

    public void setEntityRelatedId(String entityRelatedId) {
        this.entityRelatedId = entityRelatedId;
    }

}
```

and the entity for the sequence is something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEQ_GENERIC_TBL"
)
public class SeqGenericTbl implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;

    public SeqGenericTbl() {
    }

    public SeqGenericTbl(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ENTITY_SEQ_GEN", 
            sequenceName = "SEQ_GENERIC", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENTITY_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Now you can get the Id from the entity of the sequence (persist it, you can rollback that tran or delete it or empty the related table later):

```
    SessionFactory sf = HBUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    SeqGenericTbl sg=new SeqGenericTbl();
    s.save(sg);

    EntityClass entity1 = new EntityClass();
    entity1.setEntityId(sg.getId());
    //NOW YOU HAVE THE ID WITHOUT PERSISTING THE ENTITY
    System.out.println(entity1.getEntityId());
```